# Python Crash Course, Testing Your Code example

Tags: python

This is to test the class; however, I am getting an error and I do not know how to fix it.

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  """Tests for 'name_function.py'"""

  def test_first_last_name(self):
    """Do names like 'Mark James' work?"""
    formatted_name = get_formatted_name('mark','James')
    self.assertEqual(formatted_name,'Mark James')

unittest.main()
```

Here's the class that is being tested.

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
  """This is where the name is formatted correctly"""
  full_name = first + " " + last
  return full_name.title()
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
/Desktop/python_work/test_name_function.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .result import TestResult
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/result.py", line 5, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 3, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/linecache.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tokenize.py", line 96, in <module>
    class TokenInfo(collections.namedtuple('TokenInfo', 'type string start end line')):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'namedtuple'
```

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: did you name one of your own files or modules `collections` ?

Comment: The exception occurs on `import unittest` - it doesn't appear to have anything to do with your class.

Comment: I didn't touch the unittest file at all

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add if '**name**' == '**main**':
    unittest.main() to your code.

The below code should fix the error -

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for 'name_function.py'"""

  def test_first_last_name(self):
      """Do names like 'Mark James' work?"""
      formatted_name = get_formatted_name('mark','James')
      self.assertEqual(formatted_name,'Mark James')
if '__name__' == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```